# -com.apple.CoreData.SyntaxColoredLogging YES is not working in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have added

> -com.apple.CoreData.SyntaxColoredLogging YES

in "Arguments Passed on Launch". But it didn't work for me. 
In addition to that,  I have added com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug & -com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1. I am able to see the core data log but I would like to see in different color